# MySQL illegal mix of collations when everything is collated the same

Tags: mysql, union, collation

I can run this query in MySQL and it works just fine. BUT, I need to do a LEFT function on ctd.FULL_DESCRIPTION (TEXT datatype) and take just the first 3600 characters and when I try to do that (using LEFT(ctd.FULL_DESCIPTION, 3600)) I get the error: illegal mix of collations (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) and (latin1_swedish_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation 'UNION'

Everything I can find on this error suggests that one of my columns is not collated the same as the others. I did a SHOW FULL COLUMNS on all the tables in this query and everything that's collated is using utf8_general_ci. The default collation of the database is also utf8. I can't find where it's getting latin1_swedish_ci anywhere. What am I missing?

```
SELECT 
CONCAT(''73'',RIGHT(CONCAT(''000000'',cd.CHANGEID),6)) AS CHANGEID, 
LEFT(cd.TITLE,80) AS CHANGETITLE, FROM_UNIXTIME(cd.CREATEDTIME/1000) AS PRJDATE, 
LEFT(sd.NAME,10) AS STATUSNAME, wo.WORKORDERID AS WOID, LEFT(wo.TITLE,80) AS WOTITLE,
LEFT(au.FIRST_NAME,10) as TECHNAME, ctd.FULL_DESCRIPTION AS CHANGEDSC
FROM servicedesk.changedetails cd, servicedesk.incidenttochangemapping itcm, 
servicedesk.workorder wo, servicedesk.stagedefinition sd, servicedesk.workorderstates 
wos, servicedesk.sduser sdu, servicedesk.aaauser au, servicedesk.changetodescription ctd 
WHERE cd.CHANGEID = itcm.CHANGEID and itcm.WORKORDERID = wo.WORKORDERID and
cd.STAGEID = sd.STAGEID and wo.WORKORDERID = wos.WORKORDERID and wos.OWNERID = 
sdu.USERID and sdu.USERID = au.USER_ID and cd.CHANGEID = ctd.CHANGEID and
cd.STAGEID NOT IN (3,2) and cd.CATEGORYID IN 
(301,2701,3601,3602,3605,3606,4201,4202,4501,4502,4801) and wos.REQUESTTYPEID IN 
(301,601)
UNION
SELECT CONCAT(''73'',RIGHT(CONCAT(''000000'',cd.CHANGEID),6)) AS CHANGEID, 
LEFT(cd.TITLE,80) AS CHANGETITLE, FROM_UNIXTIME(cd.CREATEDTIME/1000) AS PRJDATE, 
LEFT(sd.NAME,10) AS STATUSNAME, '''' AS WOID, '''' AS WOTITLE, '''' AS TECHNAME, 
ctd.FULL_DESCRIPTION AS CHANGEDSC
FROM servicedesk.changedetails cd, servicedesk.stagedefinition sd,
servicedesk.changetodescription ctd
WHERE cd.STAGEID = sd.STAGEID and cd.CHANGEID = ctd.CHANGEID and cd.STAGEID NOT 
IN (3,2) and cd.CATEGORYID IN
(301,2701,3601,3602,3605,3606,4201,4202,4501,4502,4801) and NOT EXISTS (
SELECT NULL FROM servicedesk.incidenttochangemapping itcm WHERE cd.CHANGEID = 
itcm.CHANGEID)
```

Comment: you could try to clean up that code you just posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was the system variable collation_connection was set to latin1_swedish_ci and everything else was utf8_general_ci. Setting collation_connection to utf8_general_ci allowed the query to run successfully.