# How to use Cast, while using UNION in mysql

Tags: mysql, union, collation

how to apply cast for 'meterscount', when applying cast it is showing the error illegal mix of collations in 'union'.

```
   (SELECT StartNo,Category,Label,User FROM ShowData  WHERE SelectList=5)
  UNION
  (SELECT '','','',CONCAT('Meter Subtotal: ',MetersCount));
```

Comment: Chek the answer of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12711756/mysql-illegal-mix-of-collations-when-everything-is-collated-the-same